# Error while creating document in Firestore through Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-firestore

I am following grahamearley's guide in setting up my google sheets to read/write to my firestore database. I have created a service account assigned to be the project owner, generated the key and stored the relevant strings in my testFunction as follows:

```
function testFunction() {
  var key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n<my private key>\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
  var email = "xxxx@<projectId>.iam.gserviceaccount.com";
  var projectId = "<projectId>";

  var firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore(email, key, projectId);

  const data = {
    "name": "test!!" 
  };

firestore.createDocument("FirstCollection", data);

}
```

However, when I try running this, I obtain the following error:

> Error: Missing or insufficient permissions. (line 33, file "Util",
>   project "FirestoreApp")

I tried setting my database rule as follows, but the function still returned an error:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

I have searched here for questions with the same error of insufficient permissions, but have not found anything that helps me.

Could someone please advise me on finding out the issue and fixing it? Thank you.

Manifest:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Paris",
  "dependencies": {
    "libraries": [{
      "userSymbol": "FirestoreApp",
      "libraryId": "1VUSl4b1r1eoNcRWotZM3e87ygkxvXltOgyDZhixqncz9lQ3MjfT1iKFw",
      "version": "22"
    }]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER"
}
```

EDIT1: Added manifest file

EDIT2: Added db rules

Comment: Can you show us which scopes you are authorizing with your manifest file?

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have edited the question and added in the manifest file as requested.

Comment: This error seems to be coming from the Library. Can you share your [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) and validate that you are letting the library write to your Firestore?

Comment: @ZektorH I clarified the original question's section on the db rules I wrote in an attempt to resolve the issue. I'd copied over the code in the rules section of firestore.

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to help you. Try reaching out to the library by creating an Issue: https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript/issues

Comment: @ZektorH thank you. I will do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have since resolved this issue. It seems the problem was with my service account. I had selected Project>Owner instead of Datastore>Cloud Datastore Owner.

Thank you for all your help rendered.